# Assist With AWS CLI S3 Bucket/Folder File Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have several folders and only certain folders contain files with ".003" at the end of their name.  These files do not have an extension.

I am interested in finding out:

1. The name of the containing folder any of those files ARE in (inside of the bucket) and possibly listed only once (no duplication)?
2. The name of the containing folder that those files are NOT in?

I know how to do a search for a file like so:

```
aws s3 ls s3://{bucket}/{folder1}/{folder2} --recursive |grep "\.003"
```

Are there CLI commands that can give me what I am looking for?

If this or something like this has been asked before please point me in the correct direction.  My apologies if so!  :)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "AWS CLI search for '.003' properly" is doable in AWS CLI, but the remaining points warrant writing basically entire post-processing program/script. Thus, you may consider writing python script for all of that, as it could be easier then trying to find some clevel one-liners with AWS CLI.

Comment: Don't believe there's any way to do this with either the API or the awscli. You can only query on prefix, not on suffix. You'll have to do this entirely client-side.

Comment: Right on.  Thanks for the help!